# Get rails exceptions to show using capybara and selenium

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, integration-testing, capybara

In using capybara and selenium to run integration tests in rails, if an exception is raised a blank white page is shown instead of the usual exception screen with the stack trace.  Is there a way to get capybara to show the stack trace pages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was not able to get the stack traces to show with Webrick or Thin, but my eventual workaround was to use Mongrel, which properly prints the stack traces to stderr.

With capybara 0.4.1.2 or later, you can configure capybara to use mongrel like so:

```
Capybara.server do |app, port|
  require 'rack/handler/mongrel'
  Rack::Handler::Mongrel.run(app, :Port => port)
end
```

Comment: You can monkey-patch Thin in spec_helper.rb or env.rb: https://gist.github.com/999621

Comment: ^^ This patch has now been merged into the latest version of Thin

Answer (score 5):

Matt's solution didn't work for me, but precisely this gist https://gist.github.com/1443408
did.

https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/226 explains in more detail why it
happens and provides explanation on what given gist does.

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me.  Thanks for pointing it out o.O

Answer (score -2):

this is most likely because the stack trace is only shown in the ***development*** execution mode (or 'environment'), and your integration tests are run within the ***production*** environment.

Of course, by tweaking the production mode settings, you may be able to make it show the exception. But it would not be the correct way. The best way is to :

- log the exception and stack trace in
  a file or in a log server (hoptoad ?)
  where the user cannot see it but you
  can
- catch the exception and render an
  error page

Hope this helps. Best regards.

Comment: I think that usually people have their Capybara tests running in the :test environment.