# Capybara: exception trace in log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, capybara, stack-trace

While running integration tests in capybara, having app raise an exception (500 error; is rendered in browser) there's no stack trace in `test.log` file. Here's the only line I see there:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 25ms
```

Am I missing something? How do I make stacktraces appear in `test.log` during integration testing?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Go examine your `config/environments/test.rb` to find the line:

```
config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = false
```

And change it to `true`.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me, but the solution of using mongrel reported here did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627928/get-rails-exceptions-to-show-using-capybara-and-selenium

Comment: config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = true by default on both test and development env! It is not working for me.

Comment: This sounds like its for Rails >= 3.  Anything for Rails 2?

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer did not work for me. I'm using Cucumber + Capybara + Rails.

[This related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44227556/1248725) helped me get the culprit error in the `test.log` file after running the Cucumber scenario.