# Where do I see the reason of a "Internal server error" when running Rails request specs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have an "Internal server error" in one of my request specs (RSpec2 and Capybara), and I just don't know where to get more information about it. I've taken a look at the test.log, but there's no particular info about the problem, there's info about Rails rendering a 500 message.

Is this normal behavior? Where can I find more info? **Somewhere** Rails has to tell me what's wrong, doesn't it?

Thanks a lot for help, this one is driving me nuts.

Comment: For a 500 error the test.log should contain an `ERROR:` line - are you sure it's not there?

Comment: "Internal server error" could only be seen in browser. So your test is `js: true`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That, unfortunately, is the normal behavior. However, the good news is that many people seem to have found certain workarounds. See: 
[Get rails exceptions to show using capybara and selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627928/get-rails-exceptions-to-show-using-capybara-and-selenium)

Also, you can see the issue discussed here: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/303

Comment: Thank you for the links. Didn't know this is "normal" behavior.